# Can the U.S print infinite money?

Tags: united-states, currency, inflation

I know that a country can't simply print money to pay debt, since it would only lower the value of the money, i. e. cause inflation.

But what about the U.S? Since their new printed money is very likely to end up somewhere else, it wouldn't increase local inflation, thus giving the U.S. infinite money.

What's wrong about this idea?

Comment: No.  It could potentially print a lot more money, but it has neither the materials or the time to print an infinite amount.

Comment: Try asking this question on https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "I know that a country can't simply print money to pay debt" countries literally print money (or, "electronic money") to pay debt.  This is the NORMAL situation.

Answer (score 3):

A country certainly can print money to pay debt (assuming that debt is denominated in the currency the country controls).

If you double the supply of US dollars (or euros or Indian rupees or any other currency), you cause inflation because the existing dollars become less valuable.  It doesn't matter where the physical currency resides (assuming that everyone knows that the money supply has increased).  If someone started producing huge amounts of gold in Canada today, the price of gold worldwide would drop.  It wouldn't matter whether that gold stayed primarily in Canada or was primarily exported, once everyone found out that gold is less scarce than they thought, its price would decline.

Comment: I agree on some extent. if the U.S started printing money indiscriminately, the U.S dollar value would certainly drop front of other currencies. But internal inflation would only increase if the printed dollars stayed inside the U.S, or am I wrong?

Comment: @CharleyR. - Internal and external inflation due to the printing of money would be the same.  If dollars were somehow more valuable in the US than in France, it would be very easy to send dollars from France to the US (or vice versa).  Any differences would be arbitraged out by currency traders in a split second.

Comment: Again I partially agree =) . That would be 100% true if the currency market were completely free. But since (almost) every country has a Central Bank that keeps dollar reserves, I don't think internal and external value of the U.S dollar would balance out so quickly.

Comment: @CharleyR. - I see no reason that dollar reserves would have anything to do with it.  If gold costs $1000/ oz today and I print enough dollars so that gold now costs $2000/ oz in the US, you can be certain that gold will also cost $2000/ oz in France.  The dollar would experience 100% inflation both inside and outside the country.  The European Central Bank would be unhappy that their dollar reserves were now only half as valuable but that wouldn't impact inflation.

Comment: This answer is factually wrong because a country may not control IT's countries currency. What about certain 3rd world countries using the USD as official currency? Or Greece (as happened in the financial crisis) having the EUR - as "its currency" but under control of the ECB.

Comment: @TomTom - Fair enough.  That's what I was trying to say in the initial parenthetical but obviously didn't it phrase it as well as I could. I've made that point clearer.

Comment: Perfect then. Yes, those are mostly (outside the EU) smaller countries ;)